# What is the maximum of $x^3y^3 + x^3z^3 + y^3z^3$ subject to $x+y+z=1$?

Tags: calculus, optimization

All variables are positive reals.

This is a math competition problem. I've tried solving it using boundary value optimization, but it's not elegant at all.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Have you tried using a Lagrangian multiplier?

Comment: @Semiclassical no, is it straight forward?

Comment: It's often a good option in problems like these, though by no means guaranteed to be the best approach.

Comment: Going through Lagrange method is quite involved. I think you should use some solver for constrained problems. May be some genius optimization guy can help you!

Comment: As such the objective is non-convex, so the Lagrangian method will not find the global optimum. We need other approaches I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may set $x=\sin^2(\alpha)\sin^2(\beta)$, $y=\sin^2(\alpha)\cos^2(\beta)$, $z=\cos^2(\alpha)$ and the problem boils down to finding the maximum of

$$ \sin^{12}(\alpha)\sin^6(\beta)\cos^6(\beta)+\sin^6(\alpha)\sin^6(\beta)\cos^6(\alpha)+\sin^6(\alpha)\cos^6(\beta)\cos^6(\alpha) $$
over $(\alpha,\beta)\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]^2$. Have a look at our friend:

$\hspace{1in}$[image]

It is tedious, but doable, to check that the only stationary point inside the domain is at $\left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ but it is not a relative maximum (by computing the hessian matrix). So the maximum is attained on the boundary and we just have to study four one-variable functions to get that the maximum is $\color{red}{\large\frac{1}{64}}$ and it is attained at $(x,y,z)=\left(0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and cyclic shifts.

Comment: In such a case (assuming that *positive means positive*) I computed the supremum and there is no maximum, but that is minor nitpicking.

Comment: This is similar to what I did, and the answer seems to be correct. I guess there is no "easy" way to tackle this one.

Comment: @darksky: well, there is some shortcut: once we get that absolute maxima are on the boundary (that is the hard part), we may freely assume $x=0$, then the problem is trivial.

Comment: I tried to argue that since the second derivatives are all positve in the given domain, the given expression is convex, so the the maximum has to be on the boundary.